# Windows software that plays video as webcam footage

Tags: video

When I'm chatting on Skype on Windows 10 I sometimes want to show the person with whom I'm chatting a video. 
Is there software that I can install that plays a video and that registers in my system as a webcam?

Comment: On what OS? Windows? Do you you need/want it to be free? open source?

Comment: [Similar question I answered here.](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/36546/23986)

Answer (score 1):

[Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/download) (any OS) plus [OBS Virtual Cam](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-virtual-cam/releases) (Windows only) can do the job.

Here's how you set it up:

- Create a scene and add a "VLC Video source".
- In the Video properties, add the video you want to play to the playlist.
- From the `Tools` menu, start the Virtual Cam
- In Skype settings, choose the correct camera (called OBS-Camera)

Pictures for the above steps:

[image: Add sceen and VLC video source]

[image: Adding video to playlist]

[image: Start virtual camera]

[image: OBS Camera in Skype]