# Virtual camera that replaces background

Tags: windows, camera

I'm looking for a virtual camera with the following properties:

- uses the real webcam to take the video
- replaces the background by a predefined picture or video
- does not need a green screen / chroma key
- streams the result as the video of the virtual camera
- ideally [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but I would even pay 40$ if it works well

There is [Zoom](http://szoom.us), which can do the replacement, but only as part of the application, not as a virtual webcam:

[image: Zoom example image]

I want a more generic solution, which would do the processing out of the application, so that this feature can be used in any application that only supports camera.

I have seen the question [Fake Virtual Camera and Microphone for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36515/fake-virtual-camera-and-microphone-for-windows), but it does not have the requirement of using a real webcam as input. The suggested Manycam has a similar feature, but needs a [green screen to do it](https://manycam.com/features/#green_screen).

Comment: There is an example at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/11/26/instance-segmentation-with-opencv/ which blurs the existing background but it should be simple enough to use a pre-existing frame for the background.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: thanks, that's a nice finding. I'm into machine learning anyways, so I could try that. Maybe I can even run it in Tensorflow on GPU so that I get a higher frame rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ChromaCam](https://www.chromacam.me/) is designed for that. It's free for personal use (with watermark) and 30 US$ one-time fee for commercial use.

The background can be replaced by some built-in pictures or by a custom picture. The result is then available as a new camera called "ChromaCam", which you select in any other application.

Here's an example:

[image: Example screenshot]

The results are not perfect. They are far from the results that can be achieved for single photos on https://www.remove.bg/de. But that may be due to limited processing power and processing time. Also, even an imperfect green screen setup without proper lighting does better - but you don't always have that available.

Anyway. I think it's worth the money and well in the limit I wanted to spend (much cheaper than the 120 US$ [ManyCam](https://manycam.com/)).