# Looking for a lightweight and free virtual webcam

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I would like recommendations for a lightweight and free virtual webcam software

It should be able to use an video file or am image as a webcam, that is, if I load a webpage that accesses video, such as this one, https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm, it should detect the virtual webcam software as a built in webcam and display what ever image/video that I selected as a source

I have used Manycam before but I am looking for something more lightweight and ad free. I don't need extra features such as filters or adding text, it's ok even if it is a completely command line based application. What is important for me, is to be able to get video/image file detected as a webcam source.

Comment: Can you explain how your request is different to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36515/fake-virtual-camera-and-microphone-for-windows?

Comment: they don't work. they add filters for existing webcams but i can't find an option for virtual webcam

Comment: Really? The question asks for a fake webcam, not filters for a real webcam. [My answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/74002/1935) suggests OBS + VirtualCam. It does not need an existing webcam.